# ng-bind-html Unable to parse correct HTML and bind it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My controller is the following:

```
   myApp.controller('actionEditController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$sce',function ($scope, $stateParams, $sce) {
        $scope.table="<p>OOPSY</p>";
        $scope.test="<p>TEST</p>";
            $.get(apiHost + "/action/entity/" + $stateParams.id)
                .success(function (response) {
                    var action = response['RESPONSE'];
                    action.params = JSON.parse(action.paramsJson);
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.table = $.hbs("/templates/action.hbs", action);
                    });
                    console.log(" table is "+$scope.table);
                })
                .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error("Error retrieving action");
                });
    }]);
```

The output of console.log(table) is:

```
<div>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="EXPIRY_SM00004_BROWSED"/>
    <input name="id" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="AC0000E1"/>
    <input name="type" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="SCHEDULE"/>
        <input name="priority" type="text" value="LOW"/>
            <input name="eventName" type="text" value="expiry.SM00004.browsed"/>
            <input name="space" type="text" value="hybrid"/>
            <input name="at" type="number" value=59400000/>
            <input name="on" type="number" value=172800000/>
</div>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

My html file:

```
<div ng-app="broConsoleApp" ng-controller="actionEditController" >
    <h2 class="marcellus text-center"> EDIT ACTION </h2>
    <div ng-bind-html="table">
    </div>
    <div ng-bind-html="test"></div>
</div>
```

The `test` is getting printed however `table` is not getting printed. I think it is because of some new line characters in the output? I tried replacing them with :
`$scope.table.replace(/\n/g,'')`)
However I am still not getting an output for table. Someone please help me in formatting this rendered output just right so that `ng-bind` can bind it.

Comment: I think you need to `'ngSanitize'` to your modules list

Comment: I have already added that dependency . That is why the test is getting printed.

Comment: Don't you need to call `$sce.trustAsHtml` on your html?

Comment: I have tried that too.I think on directly giving the HTML it calls $sanitize on it otherwise it does not. Anyway i have tried $sce.trustAsHtml too :\

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any thing wrong with the html with regards to special characters etc. I am begining to think ngBindHtml cannot handle this at all.

PLease check the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PcAUERYziJtw0k1f1XjT?p=preview

I took the [plunker from angular JS](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEVu9EQ1pVUnQAWZ0PxQt.;_ylu=X3oDMTByMG04Z2o2BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2JmMQR2dGlkAw--/RV=2/RE=1432007621/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fapi%2Fng%2Fdirective%2FngBindHtml%23%21/RK=0/RS=pwfxr1ZRPuoHJailLr6aJOpWYyM-) and modified it to add just one of the input buttons in your html and it does not render.

```
$scope.myHTML =
       'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>' + 
       '<input name="name" type="text" value="EXPIRY_SM00004_BROWSED"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be working with `$sce.trustAsHtml` :

view:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="table"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html="test"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.table = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>this is a test</p>');
  $scope.test = $sce.trustAsHtml('<h3>TEST</h3>');
});
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/r646z10y/1/

Comment: But is it not supposed to just sanitize and return the html if we dont trustAsHtml explicitly?